# width in kableExtra column_spec not exact

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want to align 2 tables with different column numbers. When using the width function of column spec I get different column widths. In my understanding a column with width 9cm should be as big as 2 columns with width 6cm and 3cm. Is my logic right?

My code:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(xtable)
df = mtcars[1:5,1:4]

df = xtable(df)
align(df) = c("l","l","r","r","r")

df %>% xtable2kable(include.rownames=FALSE) %>%   column_spec(1, width = "6cm") %>% column_spec(2, width = "3cm") %>%
column_spec(3, width = "3cm") %>%  column_spec(4, width = "2cm") %>% row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#2F2E41")

df = mtcars[1:5,c(1,3,4)]
df = xtable(df)
align(df) = c("l","l","r","r")
df %>% xtable2kable(include.rownames=FALSE)  %>%  column_spec(1, width = "9cm") %>%
column_spec(2, width = "3cm") %>% column_spec(3, width = "2cm")  %>% row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#2F2E41")
```

[image: My Output]

Ofc I can manually set up the width until the tables are perfectly aligned. Or is there a better method to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LaTeX, there's a separation between each column as well as a width.  The size of the separation is in `\tabcolsep`.  When you have more columns you get more separators, and so a wider table overall.

You could fix this problem by setting the separation to zero, e.g. putting this LaTeX code early in your document:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
```

In LaTeX I think you could also set the width of the wide column to 9cm plus `\tabcolsep` so you keep the separation in other places, but I'm not sure if `kableExtra` supports that.

Edited to add:

This seems to work without modifying `\tabcolsep`:  create a new length including it (actually twice, you get the separation on both sides), and use that.  You'd put code like this early in the document

```
\newlength{\widecolsize}
\setlength{\widecolsize}{9cm}
\addtolength{\widecolsize}{2.0\tabcolsep}
```

and then produce the table using this code:

```
df %>% xtable2kable(include.rownames=FALSE)  %>%  column_spec(1, width = "\\\\widecolsize") %>%
column_spec(2, width = "3cm") %>% column_spec(3, width = "2cm")  %>% row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#2F2E41")
```

Comment: setting \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} gives me exactly the behavior I want to have thank you :)